# Activity to ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

We developed a lot ago application in 2.2 api in which we created a lot activities and used TabActivity for tab.

now when we are running current application in JellyBean version  the tabs are not showing while the application running,it shows Tabactivity has deprecated in our source code.

I have also read the Backward compatability v4 and also following the example
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/

Conclusion: For Tabs defination FragmentActity requires ListFragment, but in our case we have Activity, so is there any solution that we had not to change our old source just try to convert activity to listfragment.

```
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    tabIntent = new Intent(this, CatalogNavigationActivity.class);
    productsTextView = new TextView(this);
    productsTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    productsTextView.setText(R.string.products);
    productsTextView.setSingleLine(true);
    productsTextView.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.TabText);
    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("products").setIndicator(productsTextView).setContent(tabIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Thanx in Advance!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. The point of the example is that you should use a TabHost and Fragments to implement a UI which you would have implemented using TabActivity earlier. To migrate you would need to make fragments from your activities and implement a main activity containing the TabHost.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need a ListFragment, you can use a Fragment. See [this example from Google](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html), it would help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply alexrs, well I already this example and updated my code followed by this example. but still its showing me blank tab on emulator.